# how to determine direction of gyroscopic couple on car?

Tags: gyroscopes

How can I determine the direction of the force acting due to gyroscopic couple on a car's wheels when it is taking a turn to it's left side?

Comment: as much i know and what i interpreted from your question that will have no effect on the car as they are tooo light weighted

Comment: it does have an effect along with centrifugal force.It can overturn a car.

Comment: is it normal wheel or you are trying to attach the gyroscope to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction of reaction on the wheels of car or any body can be simply known by rotating the axis of spin to the axis of reactive gyroscopic couple.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the vehicle moves along a curved path having radius while taking turn,the centrifugal force acts radially outward.